# R grepl not giving desired result loading CSV

Tags: r, grepl

I dont know what I could be overlooking here but I am importing a csv file with a bunch of names into a data.frame. When I pull the data frame value and run grepl against it there is no match. If I take that same value and manually create a string it matches fine. Any help would be appreciated.

I obviously cant give you the CSV or the data source so I have tried to include all the code below.

After further look, it seems the string no longer has a space

```
> Parks[1,2]
[1] "Abraham Lincoln Birthplace National Historical Park"
> typeof(Parks[1,2])
[1] "character"
> grepl(" ", Parks[1,2], fixed = TRUE)
[1] FALSE
> grepl("National Historical Park", Parks[1,2])
[1] FALSE
> grepl("National", Parks[1,2], fixed = TRUE)
[1] TRUE
> grepl("National Historical Park", "Abraham Lincoln Birthplace National Historical Park")
[1] TRUE

> grepl(" ", "Abraham Lincoln Birthplace National Historical Park")
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Based on your example this should work fine. How are you reading your `.csv` file into R? `read.csv`, `data.table::fread`?

Comment: Its after I read. Im trying to locate the source of the problem. But when I read in the csv from source and do this grepl works fine. However this is about 100 actions after I read in the csv. Something between the initial read and this grepl action is causing this.

Comment: Voting to close this question as it simply states a consequence of a earlier problem in a script. This issue doesn't have anything to do with `grepl` or the provided code.

Comment: Well I think it would still be related to using grepl and getting a desired result. See update above.

Comment: All the spaces are showing up as \u so grepl does not match them with space.

Comment: You need to post a sample of your data using the dput function.  There is no enough information to help.

Comment: @Dave2e I agree in most cases this makes sense however the issue was with unicode characters built in, which does not show up in dput. So it was not included for this reason. The example above with grepl showing false for a space sufficiently shows the issue I was having. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blank spaces were unicode \u2022 characters. Running the following code before grepl results in the desired result.

```
> Code <- Parks[1,2]
> Code <- gsub('[^\x20-\x7E]', ' ', Code)
> grepl(" ", Parks[1,2], fixed = TRUE)
[1] TRUE
> grepl("National Historical Park", Parks[1,2])
[1] TRUE
```